# Line Drawing on stage

Tags: android, libgdx, stage

There are few actors on stage, lines are drawn connecting centers of them, like a graph, Nodes and edges. Nodes are gradable. On Drag I am using the following code

```
   public void touchDragged(InputEvent event, float eventOffsetX, float 
     eventOffsetY, int pointer) 
                {
                    float deltaX = eventOffsetX - self.grabOffsetX;
                    float deltaY = eventOffsetY - self.grabOffsetY;

                   self.moveBy(deltaX, deltaY);
                    moveCoordinatesBy((int)deltaX,(int)deltaY);
                    }
```

the Method moveCoordinatesBy is updating the coordinate of the center of the node. which is used to draw lines (Edges) connecting the. This is working Fine.

My problem is - When I am using moveTo action for Nodes, I need to update edges at the same time. For this I need to update coordinates of there center. To do this I am using the following code in the act method of the Node -

```
  public void act(float dt)
    {
    super.act(dt);


    Vector2 loc = new Vector2();
    loc.x = self.getX()+ self.getWidth()/2;
    loc.y = self.getY() + self.getHeight()/2;
    Vector2 v = new Vector2();
    v = self.localToStageCoordinates(loc);

   setCoordinates((int)v.x, (int)v.y);
   }
```

The coordinates I am getting are not center of the node, they are almost multiplied by 2. Am I doing something wrong?

And also `getWidth()` and `self.getHeight()` returning double the size. When actor (node) is scaled  `getWidth()` and `self.getHeight()` are returning arbitery values depending on how for it is located on stage. Further from (0,0) larger the returned value.

Answer (score 0):

```
v = self.localToStageCoordinates(loc);
```

above line of code not needed, beacuse all the actors were directly added to the stage. By removing `localToStageCoordinates(loc)` its working fine now.